# d3.js: Ordinal scale

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am drawing line chart but unable to figure out the scale for x-axies I am using ordinal scale because i am showing categories on x-axis here is the code for scaling. please let me know what i am doing wrong here.

```
var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
       .domain(xExtents)
       .range([padding, w - padding * 2]);
```

here is the sample code sorry for putting all javascript and HTML at one place.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
   
   .axis path,
   .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
   }
   
   .axis text {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
   }

   .y1 {
    fill: white;
    stroke: orange;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
   }

   .y2 {
    fill: white;
    stroke: red;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
   }

   .y3 {
    fill: white;
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
   }

   .line {
     fill: none;
     stroke-width: 1.5px;
   }

   div.tooltip {
             position: absolute;
             text-align: center;
             width: 50px;
             height: 10px;
             padding: 5px;
             font: 10px sans-serif;
             background: whiteSmoke;
             border: solid 1px #aaa;
             pointer-events: none;
             box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #888;
            }

            .legend {
             padding: 5px;
             font: 10px sans-serif;
             background: yellow;
             box-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #888;
            }

            .title {
             font: 13px sans-serif;
            }

  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <script type="text/javascript">

    //Width and height
    var w = 500;
    var h = 300;
    var padding = 50;
      
          
    var dataset = [
        [ 
            {x: "USA", y: 0}, 
            {x: "UK", y: 0}, 
            {x: "BRAZIL", y: 2}, 
            {x: "KORIA", y: 0}, 
            {x: "JAPAN", y: 0}, 
            {x: "CHINA", y: 0}
        ],
        [
             {x: "USA", y: 3}, 
            {x: "UK", y: 4}, 
            {x: "BRAZIL", y: 1}, 
            {x: "KORIA", y: 3}, 
            {x: "JAPAN", y: 1}, 
            {x: "CHINA", y: 2}
        ],
        [
             {x: "USA", y: 2}, 
            {x: "UK", y: 0}, 
            {x: "BRAZIL", y: 2}, 
            {x: "KORIA", y: 3}, 
            {x: "JAPAN", y: 4}, 
            {x: "CHINA", y: 1}
        ]
    ];

    var color_hash = {  0 : ["apple", "green"],
         1 : ["mango", "orange"],
         2 : ["cherry", "red"]
       }                      
    
    // Define axis ranges & scales        
    var yExtents = d3.extent(d3.merge(dataset), function (d) { return d.y; });
    var xExtents = d3.extent(d3.merge(dataset), function (d) { return d.x; });
         
 var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .domain(xExtents)
        .range([padding, w - padding * 2]);

 var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, yExtents[1]])
        .range([h - padding, padding]);


 // Create SVG element
 var svg = d3.select("body")
     .append("svg")
     .attr("width", w)
     .attr("height", h);


 // Define lines
 var line = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.y1, d.y2, d.y3); });

 var pathContainers = svg.selectAll('g.line')
 .data(dataset);

 pathContainers.enter().append('g')
 .attr('class', 'line')
 .attr("style", function(d) {
  return "stroke: " + color_hash[dataset.indexOf(d)][1]; 
 });

 pathContainers.selectAll('path')
 .data(function (d) { return [d]; }) // continues the data from the pathContainer
 .enter().append('path')
   .attr('d', d3.svg.line()
     .x(function (d) { return xScale(d.x); })
     .y(function (d) { return yScale(d.y); })
   );

 // add circles
 pathContainers.selectAll('circle')
 .data(function (d) { return d; })
 .enter().append('circle')
 .attr('cx', function (d) { return xScale(d.x); })
 .attr('cy', function (d) { return yScale(d.y); })
 .attr('r', 3); 
   
    //Define X axis
 var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
         .scale(xScale)
         .orient("bottom")
         .ticks(5);

 //Define Y axis
 var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
         .scale(yScale)
         .orient("left")
         .ticks(5);

 //Add X axis
 svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "axis")
 .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - padding) + ")")
 .call(xAxis);

 //Add Y axis
 svg.append("g")
 .attr("class", "axis")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + padding + ",0)")
 .call(yAxis);

 // Add title   
 svg.append("svg:text")
     .attr("class", "title")
    .attr("x", 20)
    .attr("y", 20)
    .text("Fruit Sold Per Hour");


 // add legend   
 var legend = svg.append("g")
   .attr("class", "legend")
   .attr("x", w - 65)
   .attr("y", 25)
   .attr("height", 100)
   .attr("width", 100);

 legend.selectAll('g').data(dataset)
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .each(function(d, i) {
        var g = d3.select(this);
        g.append("rect")
          .attr("x", w - 65)
          .attr("y", i*25)
          .attr("width", 10)
          .attr("height", 10)
          .style("fill", color_hash[String(i)][1]);
        
        g.append("text")
          .attr("x", w - 50)
          .attr("y", i * 25 + 8)
          .attr("height",30)
          .attr("width",100)
          .style("fill", color_hash[String(i)][1])
          .text(color_hash[String(i)][0]);

      });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is xExtents returning?

Comment: ooh so what should I have to use to return all the values ?

Comment: no, i mean what does xExtents hold? What is its value?

Comment: it holds usa and china.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show different categories on x axis (in your case, there are five countries with corresponding data), the x scale setting should be using `rangeBands` or `rangeRoundBands` for ordinal data. (see `ordinal.rangeBands` and `ordinal.rangeRoundBands` in official api documents).

```
var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
   .domain(xExtents)
   .rangeRoundBands([padding, w - padding * 2], 0.1);
```

`range` is often used with linear type of data. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

First Problem:

Use this `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js`

Instead of this `http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js`

Second Problem:

```
d3.extent(d3.merge(dataset), function (d) { return d.x; }
```

will return `["BRAZIL", "USA"]`

You need all the unique countries.

```
var countries = d3.merge(dataset).map(function(d){return d.x});
countries = d3.set(countries).values();//unique countries


var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
       .domain(countries)
       .rangeBands([padding, w - padding * 2], 1);
```

this will return `["USA", "UK", "BRAZIL", "KORIA", "JAPAN", "CHINA"]`

Last Problem:

```
var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
       .domain(countries)
       .rangeBands([padding, w - padding * 2], 1);//with ordinals we give range bands
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Yw1KRR6B8nIju7zz1kqt?p=preview)

Hope this helps!